# How to print the iteration inside an array (table) in COBOL?

Tags: cobol

I'm trying to print only one of the elements of this COBOL table, but it seems I'm having trouble in understanding how arrays (tables) in COBOL work!

```
data division.
       working-storage section.
       01 m-airlines.
         05 m-united occurs 3 times.
           10 m-u-a330 pic 9(1) value 3.
           10 m-u-a321 pic 9(1) value 1.
           10 m-u-a300 pic 9(1) value 5.
         05 m-delta occurs 3 times.
           10 m-dl-a330 pic 9(2) value 35.
           10 m-dl-a321 pic 9(2) value 27.
           10 m-dl-b777 pic 9(2) value 20.

       procedure division.
           display "number of Delta's Airbus a330: " m-delta(1,1).
```

I get this error:

> Too many subscripts.

Comment: try **m-delta(1)**

Comment: Unfortunately m-delta(1) returns all the values in second array (352720). I only need 35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the tables your code generates. This isn't what you intented.

```
             +-------------+-------------+-------------+
m-united(1): | m-u-a330(1) | m-u-a321(1) | m-u-a300(1) |
             +-------------+-------------+-------------+
m-united(2): | m-u-a330(2) | m-u-a321(2) | m-u-a300(2) |
             +-------------+-------------+-------------+
m-united(3): | m-u-a330(3) | m-u-a321(3) | m-u-a300(3) |
             +-------------+-------------+-------------+

            +--------------+--------------+--------------+
m-delta(1): | m-dl-a330(1) | m-dl-a321(1) | m-dl-b777(1) |
            +--------------+--------------+--------------+
m-delta(2): | m-dl-a330(2) | m-dl-a321(2) | m-dl-b777(2) |
            +--------------+--------------+--------------+
m-delta(3): | m-dl-a330(3) | m-dl-a321(3) | m-dl-b777(3) |
            +--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Perhaps, this is what you want:

```
01 AIRLINE-TABLE.
   05 M-U-A330     PIC 99 VALUE 3.
   05 M-U-A321     PIC 99 VALUE 1.
   05 M-U-A300     PIC 99 VALUE 5.
   05 M-U-B777     PIC 99 VALUE 0.
   05 M-D-A330     PIC 99 VALUE 35.
   05 M-D-A321     PIC 99 VALUE 27
   05 M-D-A300     PIC 99 VALUE 0.
   05 M-D-B777     PIC 99 VALUE 20.
01 FILLER REDEFINES AIRLINE-TABLE.
   05 AIRLINE OCCURS 2 TIMES.
      10 NUM-A330  PIC 99.
      10 NUM-A321  PIC 99.
      10 NUM-A300  PIC 99.
      10 NUM-B777  PIC 99.
```

which generates:

```
            +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
airline(1): | num-a330(1) | num-a321(1) | num-a300(1) | num-b777(1) |
            +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
airline(2): | num-a330(2) | num-a321(2) | num-a300(2) | num-b777(2) |
            +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+

... DISPLAY "Number of Delta's Airbus a330 : " num-a330(2)
```

Or this:

```
01 AIRLINE-TABLE.
   05 M-U-A330     PIC 99 VALUE 3.
   05 M-U-A321     PIC 99 VALUE 1.
   05 M-U-A300     PIC 99 VALUE 5.
   05 M-U-B777     PIC 99 VALUE 0.
   05 M-D-A330     PIC 99 VALUE 35.
   05 M-D-A321     PIC 99 VALUE 27
   05 M-D-A300     PIC 99 VALUE 0.
   05 M-D-B777     PIC 99 VALUE 20.
01 FILLER REDEFINES AIRLINE-TABLE.
   05 AIRLINE OCCURS 2 TIMES.
      10 AIRPLANE OCCURS 4 TIMES.
         15 NUM-PLANES PIC 99.
```

which gives

```
            +------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
airline(1): | num-planes(1, 1) | num-planes(1, 2) | num-planes(1, 3) | num-planes(1, 4) |
            +------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
airline(2): | num-planes(2, 1) | num-planes(2, 2) | num-planes(2, 3) | num-planes(2, 4) |
            +------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+

... DISPLAY "Number of Delta's Airbus a330 : " num-planes(2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the code, you've two table elements (or) 2 one dimensional tables, `m-united` and `m-delta`. To refer to an item in a table, you should use the data-name of the table element, along with its occurence number(subscript) in parentheses. This is called as **Subscripting**. As @Bruce Martin mentioned in the comments, you should try `m-delta(1)` to refer the first element in the table.

The way you've referred the table element, `m-delta(1,1)` is applicable for two dimensional table. This way of referring is wrong as you haven't defined a 2D table. Rather you've defined 2 one dimensional tables. See [Nesting tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/tasks/tptbl05.htm) for more information on creating 2D/3D tables.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually what I meant was that I'm trying to print only one of the elements of the array (number of Delta's Airbus a330 : 35). by doing m-delta(1), it will return 352720, which is all of the elements of the second array. Is there any way that I can only print 35?

Comment: Hi @Masood, try ```m-dl-a330(1)```.

Comment: That works, but it seems the concept of arrays in COBOL is completely different than other programming languages like C#. for example, if you have public static int[,] array = new int[3,2]{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}; you can call the first item of the first element like:
 public static void Main()
 {
  Console.WriteLine(array[0,0]);
 }   but I don't know how to do it in COBOL, rather than actually calling m-dl-a330 which is the element itself.